# Passing in a count / counting list items in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

Creating a slideshow with Ionic / Angular and just need a way now of passing in the total number of slides.

Currently its hardcoded:

```
.directive('imageslider', function() {
    return {
        scope : true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // hardcoded here
            scope.totalSlides = 2;
        }
    }
 });
```

My HTML is:

```
<div imageslider>
    <img ng-repeat="image in tile.data" src="img/product-images/{{image}}">
</div>
```

I need a way of getting the amount of img's that are output via the repeat and use that count in my directive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your directive a scope :

```
<div imageslider nbofelements="tile.data.length">
    <img ng-repeat="image in tile.data" src="img/product-images/{{image}}">
</div>
```

And in your directive :

```
.directive('imageslider', function() {
    return {
        scope : {
              nbofelements:'=nbofelements'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // hardcoded here
            scope.totalSlides = $attr.nbofelements;
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this looks to only pass through wording of "tile.data.length" when console logging that Is what is returned in the directive.